# The space character restriction to make </head> optional

Tags: html

The HTML5 reference [states](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#optional-tags):

> A head element's end tag may be omitted if the head element is not
>   immediately followed by a space character or a comment.

What does this "space character" restriction mean? I can only think that something like

```
<title>My Page</title><p>Some stuff.</p>
```

is valid, while

```
<title>My Page</title>
<p>Some stuff.</p>
```

is not, as the implicit `</head><body>` tags would not surround a newline. But I feel I'm off the mark. A clarifying example will be greatly appreciated.

Thanks to all!

Comment: I'd vaguely guess the intent in combination with the following rule is "if `</head>` and `<body>` are both omitted, it's unclear to which side spaces and comments in between them go, so we're forbidding that entirely."

Comment: @UlrichSchwarz — Not quite. It doesn't forbid the construct, it just explains that you can't use the implicit end-of-head in the middle of markup that is allowed inside or outside the head element.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It just means that since comments and space characters may appear inside the head element, they will not implicitly end the head element.

So if you want want the comment (for example) after the head element is closed and not *just before* it is closed, then you have to use an explicit `</head>`

i.e.

```
</title> <!-- foo --> <body>
```

means the same as

```
</title> <!-- foo --> </head><body>
```

and there is no way to represent

```
</title></head> <!-- foo --> <body>
```

without using an explicit `</head>`

Comment: Also note that the spec allows you to omit <head> completely; in fact, a document that only consists of `<!doctype html><title></title>` is still completely valid.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm pretty sure that's what was meant, but I can't escape the feeling that, assuming you want to omit HEAD and BODY tags altogether, the only way to do so while keeping these conditions verbatim is to keep together (no spaces, newlines, tabs) the last child element of HEAD and the first child element of BODY, as in my example.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation is referring to the other end of the element (where `</head>` would normally go).

For example:

```
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
<body>
...
```

is okay, but this apparently is not:

```
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
  <body>
```

Nor is this:

```
<head>
    <title>Hello World</title>
<!-- This is a comment -->
```

However (and this is a big however), you should never do this. It leads to confusing code, may supported poorly by some browsers, and may be invalid in future version of HTML. Keep it clean and stable by using good, readable markup.

Comment: Both of those are OK. It is just that the spaces and the comment are treated as appearing inside the head, not after it.

Comment: The syntax is very well supported by browsers, and has such a legacy that it seems very unlikely to ever be made invalid in future (XHTML was an attempt at that and it failed).